# SKPaymentTransaction transactionIdentifier format

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

We have recently implemented Apple in-app purchases of consumable products for our ios app. As part of the buy-flow we log the completed transaction ids on our server (i.e. the transactionIdentifier of SKPaymentTransaction). When we check our logs we see two types of transaction ids:

1. Many have this form "120000094272147"
2. Some have this form "C12B6264-2D30-41B4-B193-34F878BEF0B7", i.e., a guid.

Searching the net, we have not been able to find any information of the expected format of the transaction id. We are wondering whether we should be alarmed by the two different types showing up, or if it is normal behavior. What are your experiences with the format of the transactionIdentifier?

Update:
We have found the problem. When we started looking at the json receipt that apples sends back when calling https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt, we could see that the product id was com.zeptolab.ctrbonus.superpower1. A quick search on the net brings up lots of hits where this is a well-known receipt used in hacks.

Comment: What iOS versions does your app support. I have a vague memory that the id format changed between 6 & 7 so if you have users on differing OS versions you might see different formats.

Comment: Good point, I will pull some data on the devices at the time of purchase and update the question with it. Perhaps there is a correlation.

Comment: At first glance there does not seem to be a correlation between ios versions and the format. We have observed both guid and non-guid for ios 7 (ipad), and non-guid for ios 6 (ipad/iphone).

Comment: Hmmm. OK my next thought is that the receipt format requirements changed between OS's so you might get stuff bought one 7, restored to 6 with the new ID and vice versa for the old ID. Sorry it's not more help.